# AdminLTE, obtener ancho de un elemento usando el plugin "pushMenu" al usar "collapsed/expanded"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

como verán estoy usando una plantilla para mi desarrollo web(AdminLTE), en este caso el AdminLTE, y estoy usando usando el jqGrid para trabajar mis registros.

Lo que quiero es obtener el ancho actual de un elemento luego de haber realizado el evento de expandir/colapsar.

```js
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

var grid_selector = "#grid-table";
var pager_selector = "#grid-pager";

//Obtener un Elemento
var parent_column = $(grid_selector).closest('[class*="col-"]');

//Redimensiono inicialmente
$(window).on('resize.jqGrid', function () {
    $(grid_selector).jqGrid( 'setGridWidth', parent_column.width() );
}) 

$(document).on('collapsed.pushMenu expanded.pushMenu', function(ev){
            var event_name = ev.type;
            if( event_name === 'collapsed' || event_name === 'expanded' ) {
               
                setTimeout(function() {
                //Aqui es donde no puedo obtener el ancho del elemento, para poder redimensionar mi jqGrid
                    var parent_column = $(grid_selector).closest('[class*="col-"]');
                    $(grid_selector).jqGrid( 'setGridWidth', parent_column.width() );
                }, 20);
            }
        });

})

</script>
```

Como verán luego de detectar el evento sea collapsed/expanded no puedo obtener el ancho actual del elemento guardado en la variable "parent_column".

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo, tenia que agregar 500 a la funcion timeout, parece que demora un poco en redimensionar. Es raro ya que yo use el valor 20 el otro template.